# Reverse FK Lookup with related name

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble with the following reverse FK lookup:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items')
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, related_name='order_items')

class OrderItemDelivery(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, related_name='deliveries')
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

How would I do the following: `OrderItem.objects.filter(order_item_delivery__stage='Beginning')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've specified `deliveries` as the `related_name`, use it:

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(deliveries__stage='Beginning')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 OrderItem.objects.filter(deliveries__stage='Beginning')
```